# When using inheritance in protobuf.net, do tags have to be unique across the entire inheritance tree?

Tags: c#, inheritance, protobuf-net

I'm having a hard time finding a clear-cut answer. My understanding from the docs is that ProtoInclude and ProtoMember tags within a class need
 to be unique, but not across the whole tree.

Meaning this should be fine:

```cs
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(Employee))]
public class Person{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class Employee : Person{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Department{ get; set; }
}
```

Is this correct? 
If so, what happens when serialized properties are overridden?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> do tags have to be unique across the entire inheritance tree?

No they do not. Your understanding is correct. protobuf-net implements inheritance as a shim via encapsulation of derived types, so the restriction is simply that the tags for the sub-types must not conflict with any other tags *inside that local type*. So:

```
// this contract is an INVALID example
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(Employee))]
public class Person{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

is invalid, as the tags of the sub-type `Employee` and the property `Name` conflict.

Outside of that type there is no conflict. Other types can use "sub-type 1" and other types can use "property 1", etc.

Comment: It gets hard to guess the "tag" number when you are using "RuntimeTypeModel.Default.InferTagFromNameDefault = true". Is there a better way?

Comment: @IúridosAnjos yes: don't guess and don't infer - define your contracts explicitly and annotate your types to indicate the tags. If you can't edit the file, you can also use a "partial class" for this